# Importing from Corel Dream 3D?

Tags: export, import

I have an old Corel (v8) Dream 3D model that I would like to import into Blender. I have been unsuccessful so far. Corel won't export to a usable file that Blender will pick up. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you list the possible file formats in wich Corel Dream 3D can export the model?

Comment: I barely used a v7 install, many years ago, iirc it supported some vrml export... I could check if I still find some more info in a few days... that could work somehow, not sure.

Comment: Export file formats include: .3dmf, .b3d, .dxf, .rd3, and .wrl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little history followed by an educated guess...

CorelDream 3D was also sold as Ray Dream Designer and RDD is still a product owned by DAZ Productions, but it's sold under the name Carrara.

So, what I'm thinking is if any software still loads that file format, it would be one of the DAZ 3D products. You may even luck out and find that it'll load into Daz Studio which is free. If there's a demo version of Carrara, you might be able to load/export it from there if the demo version allows exporting. From there, you could export it as a Wavefront .obj file and bring it into Blender.

Failing that, if you can still get CorelDream 3D to run, load the model and do screenshots of front, side, top, etc. and load the screenshots as image planes into Blender and redo the model. Of course, if it's terribly complex, it may take some time.

Not a definitive answer, I know. I went down this same road with models from Sculpt-Animate 4D. Yeah, I know, nobody remembers that one :) I ended up recreating the models from scratch in Blender which didn't take nearly as long as I thought it would.

I hope you find a solution and that this has helped in at least some small way.

Comment: Wow someone else that remembers the Amiga!

Comment: LOL! Yeah, that's me busted. :)

Comment: I have DAZ. Unfortunately, it wouldn't import. It supports the modern file types, but Corel 8 is pretty old. Copying the parts as planes into Blender may be the way I'll have to go. The object will have to be broken down quite a bit. Thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options which i have tried and tested myself:

- 1: export your Corel dream model as a .3dmf file and open with Accutrans3D, which is a very good app for conversions with lots of export options.
- 2: Corel dream 3d is a rebadged edition of Raydream designer4. What you can do is open your file with Raydream Studio 5.5 which can then export Corel dream models into .OBJ or .3ds files with adjustable flags.
  Being honest to the OP, I have never used blender, so I can't say how well these two export formats translate to blender.
- In either case the geometry works well in Accutrans3D,  but textures/shaders isn't included, so you will have to redo all the texture work in blender
  Best of luck